# Is it possible to render Stripe success page with thymeleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf, stripe-payments

Previously on Stripe, a payment would trigger a custom endpoint of mine with a ChargeRequest object, which would return a thymeleaf page (I could add as many custom parameters as I wanted to the Model, for rendering in the UI).

Now with the SCA compliance it seems like we have to define the actual URL for the 'success' page without any custom params.

Is there any way around this?